# RedisTemplate keys(String pattern) method is giving empty set

Tags: java, jedis, spring-data-redis

Using `org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate` for storing data in redis server. I have the keys in pattern similar to "abc@xyz@pqr". Wanted to get all the keys which have the starting letters as "abc", and was using `RedisTemplate.keys(String pattern)` method for the same as Below:

```
Set<String> redisKeys = redisTemplate.keys("(abc).*");

for (String key : redisKeys) {
    System.out.println(key);
}
```

But its always giving me empty set.

```
// tried this pattern also 
Set<String> redisKeys = redisTemplate.keys("abc*");
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Does `redisTemplate.keys("*");` return anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure to use `StringRedisSerializer` to serialize keys. Spring Data Redis defaults to `JdkSerializationRedisSerializer` which does not allow glob-style search because of the way it works.

Check out the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:serializer) for more details.